# I exchanged for AGIX tokens on my Trezor One but cannot access them. Any ideas on how to get them?

Tags: token, converter

It shows on my Trezor One that my AGIX tokens were rexeived but my Etherium account shows nothing there. Do I need another wallet to sync with my Trezor in order to access these tokens. I would like to eventually convert them and hold them on the Cardano blockchain.

Comment: This question is not about Cardano, try to ask in the SingularityNET specific channels.

Comment: it is about Cardano in the sense that I am trying to convert these tokens to be used on the Cardano blockchain. I am trying to use the Erc-converter to move these tokens from Etherium to Cardano.